# Editing php.ini

Tags: php, e-commerce

How do I edit php.ini when my host doesn't give me access to the core file? Is there a way to create a "sub" php.ini? If so, how would I make my apps pick up the subsequent file and use that instead of the master file (that I don't have access to edit)? It's a typical shared web host if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

If your host allows it, you can use an Apache directive in an `.htaccess` file to override the INI path. (Most shared hosts, however, don't allow this.)

You might also be able to change certain individual settings via the [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function in your script - again, if your host allows it.

Comment: .htaccess wasn't an option, but ini_set was a great thought, that worked. I just socketed my directives into a separate settings file and included() it in my scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the built-in function `ini_set()`.